# Universal Analytics Channel Grouping by URL Anchor

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I would like to group links to my page by url anchor. For example:

**abc.com#Facebook -> Analytics Channel Grouping -> Social**

I have tried to read the Anchor via a Tag Manager Macro and put it into a custom dimension, but i can't select custom dimensions in Analytics Channel Grouping settings.

I have also tried just to set "Landing Page URL" ends with "#Facebook" with no success.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use channel grouping than you should rewrite the medium of your hits. This can be done by setting campaignMedium custom field in your Universal Analytics tag.

For example, you can send a pageview with your custom medium with every click on marked links.

But you should understand,  that this approach will break all sessions with clicks on marked links. So maybe you should try content grouping instead of channel grouping.